# CSS rendering in same browsers in different OS

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

While designing a website, i have to specify different CSS for positioning of elements in same browsers in different OSes. For example i am specifying different pixels for an element in firefox for linux, mac and windows. Same is the case for chrome.

I had to write different CSS using jquery( for different OS ). Why is CSS being rendered differently for same browsers across different OS. And is there a way to solve this rendering problem by a way other than jquery?

Comment: What i am looking for is that if i have some elements perfectly aligned in chrome, then how can i make sure that they will be perfectly aligned in firefox also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each browser has a set of inbuilt CSS rules it follows; things like the amount of padding by default on a `h1` element etc.

You can use a 'normalising' stylesheet (aka (CSS reset'), such as [this](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/), to reset every browser to the same point so your CSS will look the same in all of them.

Comment: but for same browser across different OS, the inbuilt rules should be same?

Comment: @Diffy not necessarily. Fonts on OSX and Windows for example are rendered very differently, so the font margins etc will changes between OS's

Comment: Also it's worth noting that you will never be able to get everything 'pixel perfect' across all browsers. There will always be minute differences. So long as the UI works in all of them I would say it's fine.

Comment: My aim is not to make pixel perfect across browsers, but perfectly aligned in a particular browser. Using normalize.css, if the elements are perfectly aligned in chrome, will they be perfectly aligned in firefox also?

Comment: There is no reason they wouldn't be.

Comment: NO because in general , they never are. So if they would be using normalize.css , then its great help to me

Answer (score 0):

**You can do Browserhacks; CSS**

**Browserhacks** is an extensive list of browser specific CSS and JavaScript hacks from all over the interwebs:
[Have a look here](http://browserhacks.com/)

**CSS Browser Selector** Clever technique to help you on CSS hacks:
You may also [have a look here](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/)

Comment: BUt these are CSS and js tricks. THey appear interesting to me and will help, but wont solve my problem

Comment: And also its not written what these hacks are for? Will i have to test each of them to find out?